# inheritance + JPA +@OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 entity candidate and candidature  , each of them have 2 children candidateX , candidateY and candidatureX , candidatureY .
The relation between candidate and candidature is   one to many

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CANDIDATURE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name="CANDIDATURE_TYPE",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public  class  Candidature {

     private Candidate candidate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CANDIDATE_ID", nullable = false)
    public Candidate getCandidate() {
        return candidate;
    }}




@Entity
@Table(name = "CANDIDATE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
@DiscriminatorColumn( name="CANDIDATE_TYPE",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public  class  Candidate {


 private Set<Candidature> candidatures;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "candidate")
    public Set<Candidature> getCandidatures() {
        return candidatures;
    }


  }
```

with this implemtation i can't join child candidateX to candidatureX , how can i solve it  ? can I make the join in children and How? 
this is children

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CANDIDATURE_X")
public  class CandidatureX extends Candidature{
    }
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CANDIDATURE_Y")
public  class CandidatureY extends Candidature{
    }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CANDIDATE_X")
public  class CandidateX extends Candidate{
    }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CANDIDATE_Y")
public  class CandidateY extends Candidate{
    }
```

my probleme is in the relation between candidateX - candidatureX
and candidateY - candidatureY

Comment: which dbms are you  using

Comment: where is your `Candidate` entity?

Comment: dbms oracle 11g

Comment: you mentioned `public class Candidature implements EntityObject`

Comment: both class's in your question are `Candidature`

Comment: A `Candidature` hold a `Set` of `Candidature` ? Isn't it `Candidate` ?

Comment: yes this is because it implements other generic entity

Comment: I fell you need to clarify the bean relation on you question because I don't see that "two" way relation you tried to explained.

Comment: yes sorry i edit it can you see now ?

Comment: you didn't implement inheritance here. Check this link http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance how to do it properly.

Comment: any one have idea ??